# i am trying to run a python code where pyaudio imported when I run my code vs code showing no module name portaudio How can I run my code?

Tags: python, pyaudio

i am trying to run a python code where pyaudio  imported when I run my code vs code showing no module name portaudio How can I run my code?

Comment: Did you installed pyaudio first ? Use "pip install pyaudio" to install pyaudio from CMD

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you give more information? Are you using Windows? OS? You can try building pyaudio via a wheel. [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/).

First check your Python version by python --version. Check if you're 32 or 64 bit. Find the specific wheel, download it and run